# What PDF format or properties must I use to make FPDM work?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using the FPDM php script (uses FPDF), which I understand requires a compatible pdf in order to merge form data.  The script's instructions say to use pdftk to do that.  I've done this, and no matter what I do... the script has errors if I try to use anything other than the example template.pdf or ex.pdf.

I can even modify the template.pdf file - just removing elements for example, and re-save it, then run the pdftk program on it, take the corresponding output file and try to use it, and even that doesn't work.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional.  I can see the template.pdf file is pdf 1.4.  I've tried saving in that old format as well, and still no joy.

What am I doing wrong??

fpdm script can be found here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

Comment: Well I can't "answer" my own question, but I can comment the answer.

Comment: I believe I have figured it out.  The following format worked for me: PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5).  I had to actually go to Save As -> choose Adobe PDF Optimized, then click the Settings button.  From there I had to choose the version from the drop-down/fly-out menu.  It failed on my first try because of something with my background ... php would crash because it used up too much memory trying to process it.  So I switched to another background and it's working fine.

I really hope that this helps somebody.  It took me literally all day to figure this out!!

Comment: If someone would help me utilize FPDM for form filling while incorporating bar code 128A with it, I would gladly mark your response as the selected answer..

Answer (score 1):

Before I found this question, my process to troubleshoot was exactly the same. No matter what I did I kept getting errors- the only thing that would work for me was the included template. Even opening the template in acrobat, changing nothing, and resaving would cause an error.

Before I even found what Woohoo Webs suggested in his answer and tried that.

> The following format worked for me: PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5). I had to
>   actually go to Save As -> choose Adobe PDF Optimized, then click the
>   Settings button. From there I had to choose the version from the
>   drop-down/fly-out menu.

I received the error: 'not compatible with fast web view' or similar. If in the PDF Optimized settings option you click 'clean up' on the left side you can untoggle fast web view.

Now I am receiving the error, PDF-Merge Error: field 'fieldname' not found. When I run it through pdftk hoping to resolve this, I receive the error: FPDF-Merge Error: Number of objects (35) differs with number of xrefs (36), something , pdf xref table is corrupted :(

To fix this issue, I had to download and install pdftk server utility on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

After install, I ran this command to repair a PDF’s corrupted XREF table and stream lengths, if possible:

```
pdftk broken.pdf output fixed.pdf
```

When I open fixed.pdf it has no issues whatsoever and populates the fields correctly. Hallelujah this was the most annoying issue in the world. To summarize, I had to take the pdf and put it through the following steps:

- Edit PDF to preference
- Save As > .pdf optimized > Settings > Acrobat 5 > uncheck fast web under cleanup
- Open file in pdftk and resave
- Install command line pdftk via ubuntu
- run command: pdftk broken.pdf output fixed.pdf

done.

Comment: Not sure what is happening to stack overflow but I received a notification that this answer had an upvote, I returned to it to see it now has only 1 and no comments. This answer had almost 10 upvotes and many comments saying thanks in the past. Something going on with stackoverflow, very very very odd